# How to handle nested md-content/div in angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs

I would like to show a hidden Inputs when user click show button in angular material 1.4. For example When collapsed it would 
[image: look like]
When user click on the show button it would look [image: Like]
Following is the code i am fiddling with.
I would like to bring the input Boxes below the Header. It seems with the nested Div Block it is not working as expected. Can anyone help?

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
  <md-tab label="Schedules">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <md-list-item ng-repeat="schedule in schedules">
            <div layout="row">
              <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Messages" ng-click="expandSchedule($index)">
                  <md-icon md-svg-src="Client/app/resources/images/icons/svg/expand_more.svg" ng-show="!schedule.showSchedule"></md-icon>
                  <md-icon md-svg-src="Client/app/resources/images/icons/svg/expand_less.svg" ng-show="schedule.showSchedule"></md-icon>
              </md-button>
              <p>{{schedule.humanReadableFormat}}</p>
              <md-button class="md-icon-button pull-right" aria-label="Messages" ng-click="delSchedule($index)">
                  <md-icon md-svg-src="Client/app/resources/images/icons/svg/close.svg"></md-icon>
              </md-button>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" ng-show="schedule.showSchedule">
              <md-input-container>
                <label>Title</label>
                <input ng-model="user.title">
              </md-input-container>

              <md-input-container>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input ng-model="user.email" type="email">
              </md-input-container>
            </div>
            <md-divider></md-divider>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-content>

      <div class="md-padding">
        <section layout="row" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap>
          <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" aria-label="Add Schedule" ng-click="clickAddSchedule()">Add New Schedule</md-button>
        </section>
      </div>

    </md-content>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write exactly why it doesn't work as expected. But I guess you have a problem with using row twice:

```
<div layout="row">
...
<div layout="row">
```

Maybe try this:

```
<div layout="row">
  <div flex>LEFT</div>
  <div flex ng-class="{hide: !schedule.showSchedule}">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```